# Connectify stops internet connection after some time

Tags: android, connection, wifi, windows-10, hotspot

I am running Connectify on Windows 10 and am sharing my Ethernet connection's internet to an Android phone and a Macbook Pro. Both devices connect flawlessly to the network and also can access the internet through it, but the internet connection stops after a random time period. The wifi connection is still up, but it returns a "no connection" error until it is disconnected and reconnected. This time period varies from a few seconds to a few hours. The Connectify tray icon then shows no connected devices (blue).
The wifi adapters power settings are set to not switch off or sleep.
I am not quite sure, but I think on Windows 7, it worked and didnt stop the connection.
What might the problem be and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you always within range of the virtual router? make sure you are in the Line Of Sight? Does the Connectify app limit your use if you are using the trial (or free) version?

Comment: I am in range (just across the room) with no obstacles in between. I am using a paid version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem but [this](http://support.connectify.me/article/34-does-connectify-work-with-windows-10) article helped me.

If you are planning on upgrading to Windows 10 from an earlier version of Windows, please uninstall Connectify prior to upgrading to Windows 10 to avoid a rare bug in the Windows 10 upgrade process.

If you have already updated to Windows 10 from an earlier version of Windows with Connectify installed, the Windows upgrade will have disabled some services Connectify depends on. The easiest way to restart these services is to simply uninstall Connectify and reinstall the latest version of Connectify.

A small percentage of Windows 10 users are reporting issues with the driver during installation. This is most often related to Kaspersky 2015 blocking Connectify's driver from being installed. You need to either upgrade to Kaspersky 2016, uninstall Kaspersky 2015, or disable Self-Defense in Kaspersky 2015. Kaspersky 2015 blocks Connectify's driver install on Windows 10 even when Kaspersky 2015 is disabled.

Comment: I have reinstalled Connectify already of course. I am not using Kaspersky, and I have also updated the wireless driver.

Comment: Try to manually setup the network using command prompt as illustrated by 
Ronnie Matthews and observe. If the behavior is still the same it's a OS , driver, hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

I just read on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-the-timeout-of-30-minutes-be-increased-for-Connectify-Lite) that the connectify app has (or had) a timeout for the free version.

---

***Alexander Gizis, Creator of Connectify.*** says, "
We just released Connectify Hotspot 2016, and have removed the timeout from the free version.  Grab it from our website and enjoy!"

---

That was what i read. So maybe you are using an older free version of connectify you could possibly fix the issue by updating the connectify software.

**IF that doesn't work there are alternatives.** ***FREE ALTERNATIVES***

since windows 7 (maybe even since xp) there is a program (or command) called ***netsh*** it comes pre-shipped with the OS that can be called from the command prompt and with a few parameters you can set up a personal hotspot.

[Read this article](https://turboblaze09.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/wifi-hotspot-with-usb-wifi-adapter/)

IF the above link does not work then just ignore the link (it may have died) instead I grabbed the most important part and pasted it below.

Run the following command in the CMD window:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=hotspot_name_here key=password_here
```

This will set the hotspot properties like hotspot name and password.

Then:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

This command will start the hotspot.

*PS. You will need to run the cmd window as an administrator. Click start, type 'cmd' in search, RIGHT click the cmd search result then click Run As Administrator*

Comment: Well, I have a paid version, and it worked before on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try uninstalling connectify, make sure you uninstall and reset setting when connectify asks you to keep them or delete them.

After rebooting create a hotspot through command prompt and the connection issue is fixed.

All the connectify does is that it runs some simple commands and make you pay for a 3 line command that you can do yourself.